# MySQL Query NOT IN another Query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.customer_id, d.date_added FROM `order` d
WHERE d.customer_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT i.customer_id 
    FROM `order` i 
    WHERE i.date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00'
)
ORDER BY d.date_added DESC;
```

The above query should return customer_id of customers who have not ordered after 15 Feb 2015 (I think). But very first record is
`17168, 2015-08-16 17:36:00`

What am I doing wrong?

This below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.customer_id,i.date_added FROM `order` i 
WHERE i.date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
ORDER BY i.date_added ASC;
```

returns expected result i.e. list of customer ids for orders placed after 15 Feb

P.S. customer_id can not be NULL

Comment: be very careful when you use `not in` as you can get unexpected time-consuming to debug results when dealing with nullability. Not saying it is your issue.

Comment: I guess the customer also had ordered bevor the feb15th.

Comment: @Drew customer_id can not be NULL.

Comment: @Jens If they ordered before 15 Feb shouldn't they still be excluded if they ordered after 15 Feb?

Comment: Add the where clause also to the outer query.

Comment: @Jens Not sure I understand. Can you help me understand the logic of it?

Comment: Is it possible new records are being added to the table while the query is running?  And, is `date_added` stored as a `datetime` value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unlikely, but possible. However, should it matter - I am getting records of orders from yesterday, 2 days ago etc in the results. Yes, date_added is datetime NOT NULL

Comment: Cross posted http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111218/3690

Comment: You should try adding an explicit cast around your literal date string.

Answer (score 0):

Can `customer_id` or `data_added` be `NULL`? Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.customer_id,d.date_added 
FROM order d
WHERE d.customer_id NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT i.customer_id FROM order i 
WHERE i.date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
and customer_id IS NOT NULL 
and i.date_added IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY d.date_added DESC;
```

**Edit**

The way you wrote your query will get you `customer_ids` with an order before '2015-02-15 14:00:00'. But if the customer ordered something after this date they might be in the resultset.

**Edit2**

Why not write

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, date_added 
FROM order
WHERE date_added <= '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
ORDER BY date_added DESC;
```

Comment: No, neither can. In any case, date_added already has a condition so NOT NULL shouldn't matter. I tried your suggestion anyway, but didn't work.

Comment: Help me understand this. I am telling MySQL to find me customer_id FROM order records such that these IDs are not present in orders placed after 15 Feb. So, how come you conclude that order placed on 16 August is a valid output? What should I do to to fix the query?

Comment: "Why not write ..." Because I am trying to get a list of customers who have NOT ordered after 15 Feb

Comment: So you want all customer having ordered up to 15 Feb: `WHERE date_added <= '2015-02-15 14:00:00'`

Comment: Nope. I don't want all customers who have ordered before 15 Feb. That may include customers who may have ordered again after 15 Feb. I want all customers who have NOT ordered after 15 Feb

Comment: ok i ran some tests and found that your original query should work if `customer_id` IS NOT NULL. Two other things might be the reason for your invalid output: a) does `date_added` have the correct colum format (datetime)? b) `order` is a reserved word in mysql. Escape it by  \`order\`

Comment: Thanks for checking. Yes, date_added has correct format. As described in OP, the inside query when run separately shows correct result.  Also, yes, I am escaping `order` - In my OP I was using ` to signify code so removed the escapes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a correlated `not exists` query to exclude all customers that have any order after the specified date:

```
SELECT o1.customer_id, o1.date_added 
FROM `order` o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `order` o2
    WHERE date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00' 
    AND o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id
)
ORDER BY o1.date_added DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with correlated not exists. Could you please walk me through the logic?

Comment: @OC2PS Sure. The `not exists` (which really is just a negated `exists` predicate) returns true if the subquery it evaluates would return any data. In the subquery the date condition is checked for each customer id in the outer query (this is the correlation). So if a customer have any order later than the specified date the subquery would return something and the `not exists` would be false and that customer excluded.

Comment: @OC2PS If the customer id can't be null (as you say) the query using `not in` should give the exact same result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the correlated not exists. Very interesting. Yeah, customer_id can not be null (even so, I even tried IS NOT NULL in the WHERE clause just to be sure), and yet NOT EXISTS query seems to yield the correct result while NOT IN doesn't.

Comment: Any chance you can also help me debug the NOT IN...just for my peace of mind :-)

Comment: @OC2PS I couldn't reproduce your problem, see the SQL Fiddle for an example where the two queries gives the same result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36688/1 Maybe I set up the test data/table incorrect, I don't know.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/115f4/1 seems to return expected result. Could I have chanced upon a bug in My SQL?

Comment: @OC2PS While a bug of course always is a possibility I would say that it's highly unlikely. A more reasonable explanation is that there was something else in your data or query that might explain it. (I'm guessing the query you posted might be a reduced form of your real query) The query simply shouldn't be able to return that value.

Comment: One possibillity would be that the OP has customer_id defined as a varchar type instead of an int, and mysql treats empty strings as NULLs, IIRC.

Comment: @wildplasser That wouldn't explain how a row with a date like `2015-08-16 17:36:00` shows up in the result as it should clearly be excluded by the condition in the subquery `not in( ... where date_added > '2015-02-15 14:00:00')`

Comment: You are correct of course. I was only speculating. It appears to me that the OP is not telling us the complete story. (such as DDL and test data)

Answer (score 0):

If you want customers who have not ordered since a certain date, I would just use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT o.customer_id, MAX(o.date_added) as most_recent
FROM `order` o
GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING MAX(o.date_added) <=  '2015-02-15 14:00:00';
```

Comment: Looks like there is a serial downvoter on the loose.

Comment: No idea why this would be downvoted as it is a correct solution. Not sure about the serial assertion though as the only other downvotes were on an incorrect answer

Comment: @jpw . . . I'm pretty sure all (or almost all) the answers were downvoted.  This happens from time to time.  If you haven't been affected, more power to you.